# Does setting a .unique(on:) constraint affect the uniqueness of the .id in fluent/vapor?

Tags: swift, database-schema, fluent, vapor, server-side-swift

As the title says:

Does setting a .unique(on:) affect the .id in fluent/vapor?

I have a "user" schema which has a .id and is also .unique(on: email). Now I have noticed that I have entries of users in the database which have different email addresses but the same ids. I thought that this should not happen because ids are also unique.

Maybe someone has an answer for me. Thanks a lot already!

```
struct CreateUser: Migration {
    func prepare(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        
    database.schema(User.schema)
        .id()
        .field("name", .string)
        .field("email", .string, .required)
        .unique(on: "email")
        .create()
    }
    
    func revert(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        database.schema(User.schema)
            .delete()
    }
}
```

The only explanation I can think of is that email and id are combined to form a primary key, or that the unique of the id is cancelled.

```
final class User: Model, Content {
static let schema = "users"

@ID                                             var id: UUID?
@Field(key: "email")                            var email: String
@Field(key: "name")                             var name: String?
    
init() {}

init(id: UUID? = nil,
     name: String?,
     email: String
) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.email = email.lowercased()
}
```

}

Comment: Hi. Can you edit your question to include the `Model` definition as well as the `Migration`? Using `unique` either singly or compound does not affect id normally.

Comment: That is, what I was thinking until I have seen 4 entries with the same id but different email addresses in my database :D. I have added the code for the model.  Thank you

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the IDs are identical? Which version of Postgres are you using?

Assuming the table is created with the `id` column marked as `PRIMARY KEY` the DB should reject duplicate IDs

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the line @ID in your model to:

```
 @ID(key: .id) var id: UUID?
```

And then re-create the table - I.e. revert and run the migration again. I believe your problem is that vapor is not ending up making the id field the primary (and therefore unique) identifier. You can confirm this by looking at the table structure in the database.

Comment: when I look at the table structure or its constraints in the database, I see the id as the primary key and the email as the unique key.

Comment: Is that after re-creating the table?

Comment: No, this is the current status, before the change.
I don't really understand this state... The primary key seems to be recognised, but is not automatically unique?

Comment: Which database back-end are you using?

Comment: I am using a PostgresSql db